# How can I scrape elements from inside divs that im scraping?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am having trouble getting my code to print what i need. I can print a full list of the divs I want to extract no problem, but when I try to extract the spans from inside my divs nothing prints.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

url = “https://reviews.solutionreach.com/vs/reviews/abate_and_ortisi?limit=50”

response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

myReviews = soup.findAll(‘div’, attrs={‘class’: ‘reviewSection’})

for item in myReviews:

    try:
          print item.contents[1].findAll(‘span’, attrs{‘class’:’rating’})[0].text
    except:
          pass
    try:
          print item.contents[1].findAll(‘span’, attrs{‘class’:’reviewTitle’})[0].text
    except:
          pass
    try:
          print item.contents[1].findAll(‘span’, attrs{‘class’:’reviewer’})[0].text
    except:
          pass
```

Here is the page I am trying to pull data from

https://reviews.solutionreach.com/vs/reviews/abate_and_ortisi?limit=50

Comment: Don't use empty `except` statement. You are skipping errors that might help in debugging. And you should show example of HTML page so we can help you.

Comment: And btw. Your quotes look weird. As you can see, code highlighter does not recognize them properly. That might be a problem.

Comment: is BeatifulSoup a mandatory requirement?

Comment: For me or for this example? If you have a better solution I would be more than happy to listen.

Answer (score 0):

```
import bs4, requests

r = requests.get('https://reviews.solutionreach.com/vs/reviews/abate_and_ortisi?limit=50')

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
for div in soup.find_all(class_="reviewBlock"):
    rating = div.find(class_="value-title").get('title')
    title = div.find(class_="reviewTitle").text
    reviewer = div.find(class_="reviewer").text
    print(rating, title, reviewer)
```

out:

```
5 Always a pleasant visit!  Dr. Ortisi has been m... Justine F.
5 I absolutely Love the office staff and Dr Ortis... Richard C.
5 Love Dr Abate: does great painless work, friend... Nicole P.
5 It is always a pleasure to be at the Doctor's off. George C.
5 Best Denists in Town Elaine B.
5  Ronald J.
5 . Sharron L.
5 A great experience. Clean professional staff and ... Crystal R.
5 I had another great experience at your dental off... Vicki M.
5  David C.
5 I really like the office and dental staff at Orti... Ami A.
5 Steve Torakis Steven T.
5 Great visit Donald F.
```

1. `find()` will scan all the descendants, no need to use `contents[1]`
2. If you want a tag, use `find()`, if you want tags, use `find_all()`
3. `rating` number is the attribute of `span` tag, not text

Comment: I get errors when trying to run your script.                                                      Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'soup' is not defined

Comment: @Derek Estrada just copy and paste, how could it be wrong?